# HTTrack returns file not found

Tags: html, html-parsing, httrack

I downloaded a website with HTTrack using the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/httrack https://www.website.com -O /Users/mainuser/Desktop/website -n -j
```

I than located the index.html file in website folder and run it. Chrome returns the message: file not found. That's funny, because normally the websites I parse with httrack work just fine on my file system. What cold be the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, using the v (verbose) flag to enable HTTrack to give you as much debugging information as possible:

/usr/local/bin/httrack "https://www.website.com" -O "/Users/mainuser/Desktop/website" -n -j -v